# How can I delete last word of sentence in StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string, java-ee-6, builder, eclipse-jee

I want to detele the last word of string in  StringBuilder here is it my code:

```
builder.append(" where");
        if(type.equals(EnumTypePrestation.OPTIQUE)){
            builder.append(" d.idDossier=p.id and d.statut=4 and  ");

        }

builder.substring(0,builder.lastIndexOf(" ")-1);
```

the builder contains :  `WHERE d.idDossier = p.id AND d.statut = 4 AND`

I want to remove the last word "AND"
can anyone help me to do that!

Comment: There are better ways to do this.  One way is to simply tack `1 = 1` onto the end of your SQL statement.

Comment: You should read the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int)

Comment: Here's a simple way: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/838096/How-can-I-remove-last-word-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 is generally to check the javadoc first, *before* asking on Stack Overflow. Had you done that, you would have found [the `StringBuilder.setLength()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength(int)) which you can use to 'set the length'. Trivially, set the length to 4 less (that same javadoc tells you that `.length()` gets you the current length, so, `builder.setLength(builder.length() - 4)` and you have your result.

But..

### It's 6, not 4.

As per your own snippet, you're adding `" AND  "` - note the spaces. That's 6, not 4.

### Swap AND

A much better way to do this is to swap where/and to the front of your appends. Instead of adding  `AND` at the end every time you append another aspect of your query, instead *start* with `AND`  (for the first entry, `WHERE` ). Now the problem has gone away entirely. If that `WHERE` thing is annoying, you're always free to start a query with `SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE true` and *then* you can get in the habit of writing each additional query rule as  `AND thingie = value` from there.

### Actually, use JDBI/JOOQ

JDBC is extremely low level and isn't really meant to be used like this. As you found, it's quite annoying to write code for it. That's because JDBC is low-level glue; it exists as common ground for DB engine builders and the JVM. Instead, use a library that makes 'talking SQL with databases from java' a *lot* easier, faster, and more sustainable (easier to maintain, test, and modify in face of change requests). Such as [JDBI](https://www.jdbi.org/) or [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org).

Answer (score 1):

It would be more logical to do less superfluous SQL.

```
    int startWhere = builder.length();
    if (type == EnumTypePrestation.OPTIQUE) {
        builder.append(" and d.idDossier=p.id and d.statut=4");
    }
    if (...) {
        builder.append(" and ...");
    }
    ...
    if (builder.length() > startWhere) {
         builder.replace(startWhere, " and".length(), " where");
    }
```

This code still is ugly. The attempt to be efficient using a StringBuilder is even error prone.

```
List<String> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
if (type == EnumTypePrestation.OPTIQUE) {
    criteria.add("d.idDossier=p.id and d.statut=4");
}
...
if (!criteria.empty()) {
    builder.append(criteria.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" and ", " where ", " ");
    // Or:
    builder.append(criteria.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(") and (", " where (", ")");
}
```

*`joining` has here 3 parameters: separator, prefix and suffix.*

There is one hard advise: do not try to make such code easier with this kind of tiny frameworks. This kind of database coding is very often done.
However the next programmer has to learn it, instead of an existing library. And the chance people program around it or the API will show up deficits, is large.
Better invest the time looking for an existing solution. You will save time on maintenance work (new features, difficult things with prepared statements, and so on).

The answer of rzwitserloot is to the point.